# Does the current task scheduler flow into ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem callbacks?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

Does the current task scheduler flow into `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` callbacks, as a part of the execution context flow?

I expect it would not, so the following debug asserts should be passing. I couldn't find any confirmation of that online.

```
var scheduler = new CustomTaskScheduler();
await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current == scheduler);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current != scheduler);
        Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default);
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    });

    await tcs.Task;
    Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current == scheduler);
},
CancellationToken.None,
TaskCreationOptions.None,
scheduler).Unwrap();
```

Answer (score 4):

> Does the current task scheduler flow into `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` callbacks, as a part of the execution context flow?

To my future self: no, it doesn't, as expected. Here's a simple `CustomTaskScheduler` to test the code in question:

```
public class CustomTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    protected override IEnumerable<Task>? GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(t =>
            base.TryExecuteTask((Task)t!), task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Inside the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` callback, the current task scheduler is indeed set back to `TaskScheduler.Default`:

```
var scheduler = new CustomTaskScheduler();
await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current == scheduler);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current != scheduler);
        Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default);
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    });

    await tcs.Task;
    Debug.Assert(TaskScheduler.Current == scheduler);
},
CancellationToken.None,
TaskCreationOptions.None,
scheduler).Unwrap();
```

Comment: `QueueUserWorkItem` queues work on the next available thread from the ***threadpool***, which is managed by the default task scheduler. if you wanted to use a custom TaskScheduler then this is one of the few valid reasons to use `StartNew` ... [for effect](https://i.imgflip.com/4f47xw.jpg)

Comment: @MichaelRandall, actually I don't want to use a custom task scheduler. Rather, I want to make sure that **when the current ambient task scheduler is non-default, I will get back the default one if I use `QueueUserWorkItem`/`UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem`**. Thus, the existing behavior is exactly what I need.

Comment: @MichaelRandall, other than that, it's quite possible to be on a `ThreadPool` thread and still have `TaskScheduler.Current != TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: Yes i agree that you can set the current task scheduler on any thread, it would be extremely limiting if you couldn't. My point was, this behaviour would be expected from `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and many other TPL methods, unless they specifically allow you to set the scheduler, or have other advanced options. I personally think the question and answer are good and a lot of this information (as once said by *stephen toub* (paraphrased)) is like air, you usually don't have to worry about it... until you do

Comment: @MichaelRandall, agree. I think that was a reasonable assumption but I really wanted to verify it :) Doing it this way was simpler than digging into https://source.dot.net.